How to Modify SQL Table Using a Custom Service in Medusa V2?
I'm currently working with Medusa V2 and trying to create a custom service inside the modules folder. However, I'm unsure how to modify the SQL table using this service in the new version.
In Medusa V1, I could easily modify the table by doing something like this in the service:
import { TransactionBaseService } from "@medusajs/medusa";
import { ReservationDate } from "../models/reservation-date";

export default class ReservationService extends TransactionBaseService {
  private readonly reservationDateRepository_;

  constructor(container) {
    super(container); // Pass the container to the base class constructor
    this.manager_ = container.manager;
    this.reservationDateRepository_ = container.reservationDateRepository;
  }

  async createReservation(
    variantId: string,
    customerId: string,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
  ) {
    return await this.atomicPhase_(async (transactionManager) => {
      const reservationRepo = transactionManager.withRepository(
        this.reservationDateRepository_,
      );

      const reservation = reservationRepo.create({
        variant_id: variantId,
        customer_id: customerId,
        start_date: startDate,
        end_date: endDate,
      });

      return await reservationRepo.save(reservation);
    });
  }
}

I was able to access the repository like this:
const reservationRepo = this.manager_.getRepository(ReservationDate);

or like this:
const reservationRepo = transactionManager.withRepository(
        this.reservationDateRepository_,
      );

This allowed me to create and save records in the SQL table using methods like create and save.
However, in Medusa V2, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Specifically, I’m confused about how to make the create, save, and other repository methods work with the new architecture.

How do I properly access the repository in Medusa V2?
How can I implement create and save operations on a custom model in the new version?

Any help or guidance on how to perform these operations in Medusa V2 would be greatly appreciated!
